# Carrot2 issues in first use

Tags: windows, carrot2

I have downloaded Carrot2 and tried it, and I received the response "Our apologies, the following processing error has occurred: org.carrot2.source.etools.IpBannedException: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden"

I have read that it is not an issue, because the number of allowed searches is limited. But it was my first search!

(Excuse my poor english, I'm not an english speaker).

Raquel

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking and steps to reproduce are missing. Please add what you've done and what you already searched (even without success or if you're not pleased with it) or tried to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The eTools document source is provided to Carrot2 by our partner, http://etools.ch. They sometimes block certain ranges of IP addresses to limit the abuse of their service and your IP might have gotten on their list even if it's not offending. See [this FAQ](http://project.carrot2.org/faq.html#ipbanned) for more information.

One way is to try Carrot2 on some other document source, such as the Bing search engine (you'll need to [generate a Bing API Key](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) to do that). Alternatively, you can cluster locally stored data from a [Lucene index](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.lucene), [Solr instance](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.solr) or [XML file](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.xml-files).